# Add image to website on Polymer 3.0

Tags: html, image, polymer-3.x

I am new at Polymer (started today :) ). I want to add an image to app-drawer, however using  is not working, I tried to install and use iron-image but I could not include because imports need to be js file and iron-image does not include js, only HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with polymer-3 may be a little confusing in the current state of development, since the documentation doesn't seem to be complete yet and the polymer-3-elements are only preview versions.

If you install the iron-image element via npm (`npm install @polymer/iron-image@next --save`) you will get the latest `polymer-3` version of that element. That element is a js file and should be possible to be imported in your project.

Here is an example from the polymer docs on how to add elements: [Polymer Docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/3.0/start/toolbox/add-elements)